# Close all buffers besides the current one in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I close all but the current buffer in Emacs? Similar to "Close other tabs" feature in modern web browsers?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [EmacsWiki: Killing Buffers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingBuffers#toc2):

```
(defun kill-other-buffers ()
    "Kill all other buffers."
    (interactive)
    (mapc 'kill-buffer 
          (delq (current-buffer) 
                (remove-if-not 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list)))))
```

*Edit*: updated with feedback from Gilles

Comment: Why do the dired buffer not being killed? I like to remove that also

Comment: dired buffers don't set `buffer-file-name` and thus the call to `remove-if-not` in the above example will preserve dired buffers (as well as scratch buffer, term buffers, help buffers, etc, anything not visiting a file). I can't think of an easy test that would close both file buffers and dired buffers, you'd need basically a whole second invocation of mapc with a different test for dired buffers.

Comment: a simple modification to kill also dired buffers  `(defun kill-other-buffers ()
    "Kill all other buffers."
    (interactive)
    (mapc 'kill-buffer 
          (delq (current-buffer) 
                (remove-if-not '(lambda (x) (or (buffer-file-name x)
                                                (eq 'dired-mode (buffer-local-value 'major-mode x))))
                               (buffer-list)))))`

Comment: It looks like in this video the man is able to do that. He opens a new Slime buffer whilst closing the GNU buffers and others. Do you have any idea how he does that? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKFcznZ28BE&t=310s

Comment: Replacing `cl-remove-if-not` with `remove-if-not` works but this does not kill `*helm..` buffers

Answer (score 109):

For a more manual approach, you can list all buffers with <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>, mark buffers in the list for deletion with <kbd>d</kbd>, and then use <kbd>x</kbd> to remove them.

I also recommend replacing list-buffers with the more advanced ibuffer: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)`. The above will work with ibuffer, but you could also do this:

<kbd>m</kbd> (mark the buffer you want to keep)
<kbd>t</kbd> (toggle marks)
<kbd>D</kbd> (kill all marked buffers)

I also use this snippet from the Emacs Wiki, which would further streamline this manual approach:

```
;; Ensure ibuffer opens with point at the current buffer's entry.
(defadvice ibuffer
  (around ibuffer-point-to-most-recent) ()
  "Open ibuffer with cursor pointed to most recent buffer name."
  (let ((recent-buffer-name (buffer-name)))
    ad-do-it
    (ibuffer-jump-to-buffer recent-buffer-name)))
(ad-activate 'ibuffer)
```

Comment: How can I return from `ibuffer`? @phils

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe `q`?  Use `C-h m` to learn keybindings, just as with any other mode.

Answer (score 22):

There isn't a way directly in emacs to do this.

You could write a function to do this. The following will close all the buffers:

```
(defun close-all-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (buffer-list)))
```

Comment: Ah, but this will close *all* buffers.

Comment: `(delete (current-buffer) (buffer-list))` should give you a buffer list that you can map `kill-buffer` across and avoid killing the current buffer.

Comment: @NickD: Yep, works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

There is a built in command <kbd>m</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `kill-some-buffers` (I'm using 24.3.50) In my  nextstep gui (not tried in a terminal but sure it's similar) you can then approve which buffers to kill.

Comment: This is especially useful when you have 1000+ buffers loaded.

Comment: @ocodo Did you mean this literally or figuratively

Answer (score 12):

```
 (defun only-current-buffer () 
   (interactive)
   (let ((tobe-killed (cdr (buffer-list (current-buffer)))))
     (while tobe-killed
       (kill-buffer (car tobe-killed))
       (setq tobe-killed (cdr tobe-killed)))))
```

It works as you expected.

And after reading @Starkey's answer, I think this will be better:

```
(defun only-current-buffer () 
  (interactive)                                                                   
    (mapc 'kill-buffer (cdr (buffer-list (current-buffer)))))
```

(buffer-list (current-buffer))  will return a list that contains all the existing buffers, with the current buffer at the head of the list.

This is my first answer on StackOverflow. Hope it helps :)

Comment: And this my friends is how elegant solutions arise from people sharing their ideas

Comment: I don;t know if the spec for `buffer-list` changed over the years, but `(buffer-list (current-buffer))` to work as the answer above indicates will *NOT* work. Do `C-h f buffer-list RET` for the current spec.

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution to be the simplest one. This deletes every buffer except the current one. You have to add this code to your `.emacs` file

```
(defun kill-other-buffers ()
      "Kill all other buffers."
      (interactive)
      (mapc 'kill-buffer (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list))))
```

Of course, then you use it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kill-other-buffers` <kbd>RET</kbd> **or** you paste the following code in the `.emacs` file too and then just press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd>

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'kill-other-buffers)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can like this one as well - kill all buffers except current one, *Messages* and *scratch* (which are handy to have, I call them "toolkit"), close redundant windows as well, living you which one window which current buffer.

```
(defun my/kill-all-buffers-except-toolbox ()
  "Kill all buffers except current one and toolkit (*Messages*, *scratch*). Close other windows."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (remove-if
                       (lambda (x)
                         (or
                           (eq x (current-buffer))
                           (member (buffer-name x) '("*Messages*" "*scratch*"))))
                       (buffer-list)))
  (delete-other-windows))
```

Comment: `(string-equal (buffer-name) (buffer-name x))` is the same as `(eq x (current-buffer))`, just less efficient.  The remaining `or` can be simplified to `(member (buffer-name x) '("*Messages*" "*scratch*"))`

Comment: Now that cl is deprecated (defines `remove-if`), is there an alternative approach? This has been extremely useful...

Answer (score 1):

I've use [crux-kill-other-buffers](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux/blob/c79985f69b7cd96edb505199bd751f71ce6d4e58/crux.el#L545) for some months.

But I want dired buffers get deleted too. @Euge's and @wenjun.yan's answers solve this. But it will delete special buffers (e.g *git-credential-cache--daemon*, *scratch*, helm operation, and etc). So I came up with this (current) solution.

```
(defun aza-kill-other-buffers ()
  "Kill all buffers but current buffer and special buffers"
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buffer (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list)))
    (let ((name (buffer-name buffer)))
      (when (and name (not (string-equal name ""))
             (/= (aref name 0) ?\s)
             (string-match "^[^\*]" name))
        (funcall 'kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Inspired from [kill-matching-buffers](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/44ad4a15a0099285a16018ad790419cb60df5815/lisp/files.el#L6181). You can add more `condition` on other buffer-name to exclude, if you want to.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/azzamsa/emacs.d/blob/master/aza-packages/aza-scripts.el) for my improved solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've used one of the solutions in this list for years, but now I have a new one of my own.

```
(defun kill-all-file-buffers ()
  "Kills all buffers that are open to files. Does not kill
modified buffers or special buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'kill-buffer (cl-loop for buffer being the buffers
                              when (and (buffer-file-name buffer)
                                        (not (buffer-modified-p buffer)))
                              unless (eq buffer (current-buffer))
                              collect buffer)))
```

cl-loop has buffers built in as a collection that you can iterate over. It gives you a chance to parse out anything you don't want to close. Here, I've made sure that it doesn't close anything you've modified, and it uses buffer-file-name instead of just buffer-name so it doesn't kill special buffers. I also added an 'unless' to take out the current buffer (though you could obviously add it to the 'when', I just thought this was clearer).

But for an even more generic solution, we can define this as a macro, and pass in a function that will apply to all these buffers.

```
(defmacro operate-on-file-buffers (func)
  "Takes any function that takes a single buffer as an argument
and applies that to all open file buffers that haven't been
modified, and aren't the current one."
  `(mapc ,func (cl-loop for buffer being the buffers
                            when (and (buffer-file-name buffer)
                                      (not (buffer-modified-p buffer)))
                            unless (eq buffer (current-buffer))
                            collect buffer)))
```

Now if you want to kill all buffers that match this, you can call it like this

```
(operate-on-file-buffers 'kill-buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun px/kill-other-buffers ()
  "Kill all other buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (buffer)
          (when (and (buffer-file-name buffer) (not (eq buffer (current-buffer))))
            (kill-buffer buffer)))
        (buffer-list)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(defvar my/kill-buffer-exceptions '("Messages" "emacs-file" "scratch"))
(defun my/kill-buffer-testfn (key lcar)
  ;; (print (list lcar key (string-match-p (regexp-quote key) lcar)))
  (string-match-p (regexp-quote key) lcar))

(defun my/kill-other-buffers ()
    "Kill all other buffers."
    (interactive)
    (mapc 'kill-buffer
          (delq (current-buffer) ; filter current buder
                ;; filter alive and not system
                (seq-filter (lambda (b) (and (buffer-live-p b) ; filter alive
                                             (/= (aref (buffer-name b) 0) ?\s) ; filter system
                                             ;; filter exceptions
                                             (not (seq-contains-p my/kill-buffer-exceptions
                                                             (downcase (buffer-name b))
                                                             #'my/kill-buffer-testfn))))
                            (seq-uniq (buffer-list))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-!") #'my/kill-other-buffers)
```

Answer (score -5):

This is what you want:

```
C-x 1
```

source: https://blasphemousbits.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/learning-emacs-part-4-buffers-windows-and-frames/

Comment: I think the reason you got down-voted was that OP is asking to close other *buffers*, not *windows*. Emacs terminology can be a bit confusing.